# How to detect double click on WebKit view on iOS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webkit, mobile-webkit

I have a WebKit view with some HTML and jQuery that can detect a double mouse click like so

```
$("#button").dblclick(function() {
  //code
});
```

This works fine on the browser but doesn't work in my iOS app when I double tap on the same button. Note that I'm not asking how to disable double-tap zoom; I've already disabled that and that's not the problem I'm trying to solve. Thanks in advance!